# checking for empty json in Titanium

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

I have been looking at the problem of detecting an empty JSON object and could not get some of the suggestions to work that I found here.

The solution that seems to work is:

```
if ( Ti.JSON.stringify ( json ) != "{}" )
```

Does anyone see any problems with this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be problematic with empty string or null values.

```
json = '';
Ti.API.log(JSON.stringify(json));  // would output ""

json = null;
Ti.API.log(JSON.stringify(json));  // would output "null"
```